# HTTPS request blocked in Windows7

Tags: vba, vbscript, windows-7, xmlhttprequest

I am calling a web page from a VB application to perform a validation, something like :

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
...
objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", ls_address, False
objXMLHTTP.Send
```

The value of *objXMLHTTP.Status* is 0 in Windows7 and 200 in Windows10.
I have a lot of people that started to have this problem yesterday (2018-01-29) so I am thinking that a Windows 7 update might have caused this?

Also, my *ls_address* is *https://...* and I have the problem in Windows7, but when I change it to *http://...* it works again.  Both work in Windows10.

Anybody has a clue where to look, Windows Defender, Microsoft Security Essentials, etc. ???

Comment: Do you have port 443 blocked?

Comment: What would block it?  I tried 2 computers in the same network, one with Windows7 and one Windows10.  Only the Windows 7 has the problem.

Comment: Sounds more like an IT/configuration issue than a programming problem though. I doubt VBA is even relevant here, could be any client.

Comment: Your firewall or router could block the port. I find it odd that it works on HTTP (which is through port 80), but HTTPS is blocked (which is port 443). Honestly, I would be surprised if it was blocked - but I am not thinking of any other solution other than what @Mat'sMug stated. 
I would at least check your UPnP or NAT settings before thinking of all the other _elegant_ solutions

Comment: Its going to be [a cypher issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36217219/692942), you need to make sure your using TLS1.2 or above as SSL 3.0 is now deprecated. That's likely what has been updated in Windows 7.

Comment: I'm confused 200 in HTTP means Success and it is finished.

Comment: From *Wininet.h* `#define HTTP_STATUS_OK                  200 // request completed`

Comment: @ACatInLove, you are right 200 is ok, but I only get  200 on a windows 10 computer.  0 with a windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with a windows 7 update as I tought first, but rather a security update on the web server that caused trouble only with windows 7 clients.

As mentionned by Lankymart, it is related to SSL/TLS protocols or cyphers.  I am not sure if I could code something different in VBA to make it work.  I tried  using Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"), but it did not work in my vba environment.

As a temporary solution, the update on the web server was undone and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line of code:

```
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Origin", ls_address
```

Also: is there any **authentication** needed?

Comment: Why do you think adding this line of code will solve the problem, can you explain your thinking?

Comment: I had a similar problem accessing a JIRA site and adding this line of code resolved the problem. As I am not sure it specifically relates to JIRA sites, I suggested this solution.

Answer (score 0):

TLS version 1.2 update in Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012, and Windows 7
https://support.site24x7.com/portal/en/kb/articles/to-update-to-tls-version-1-2

Comment: You probably could explain a little more what to do and what's explained on the link. Ideally your answer would be self explicit without following the link.