# msxml6.dll error '80072f7d' An error occurred in the secure channel support

Tags: asp-classic

I have seen this question floating around but no answer as yet. My server is using TLS 1.2 as is the server I am requesting from

```
<!--#INCLUDE virtual="/json/jsonObject.class.asp"-->
<%
    Session.LCID=2057
    Dim jsonString, jsonObj, outputObj

    Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.SetOption 2, xmlhttp.GetOption(2)
    xmlhttp.open "POST", "https://xxx.domain/api/auth", 0
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send "ClientId=X&ClientSecret=Y&GrantType=Z"
    jsonString = xmlhttp.responseText    
    response.write(jsonString)
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing 

    set jsonObj = new JSONobject
    set outputObj = jsonObj.parse(jsonString)

    'response.write(outputObj("access_token"))
%>
```

This gives me

```
msxml6.dll error '80072f7d'

An error occurred in the secure channel support
```

I've seen some suggestions on dropping server from ServerXMLHTTP so I did that and I get

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xmlhttp.GetOption'
```

I resolve that and then it says SetOption isn't supported. I remove that line entirely and then it says ClientID is not being sent

When I try and use https://markohoven.com/2020/03/06/msxml2-serverxmlhttp-and-tls1-2/ I get

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'

Invalid procedure call or argument: 'XMLServer.Option'
```

I then tried the below

```
<%
Set winhttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
winhttp.open "GET", "https://howsmyssl.com/a/check", False
winhttp.Send
Response.Write winhttp.responseText 
%>
```

This gives the below that suggests I am not using TLS 1.2?

```
{
    "given_cipher_suites": ["TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA", "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"],
    "ephemeral_keys_supported": true,
    "session_ticket_supported": false,
    "tls_compression_supported": false,
    "unknown_cipher_suite_supported": false,
    "beast_vuln": true,
    "able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting": false,
    "insecure_cipher_suites": {
        "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA": ["uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order"],
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA": ["uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order"],
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5": ["uses RC4 which has insecure biases in its output"],
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA": ["uses RC4 which has insecure biases in its output"]
    },
    "tls_version": "TLS 1.0",
    "rating": "Bad"
}
```

The server I am using Windows Server 2008. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An error occurred in the secure channel support - Classic ASP HTTP Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354992/an-error-occurred-in-the-secure-channel-support-classic-asp-http-request)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: The problem is you are using Windows Server 2008 which pre-dates TLS 1.2 we had to upgrade our old servers to get TLS 1.2 working. I think if it was running Windows Server 2008 R2 it would have been okay. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841060/692942) in that duplicate target suggests adding registry keys to support TLS 1.2, not sure if you've tried that but can't see how that wasn't helpful, it's pretty much the same issue you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade your Windows server to TLS 1.2 (any version is fine), follow these steps:

[Classic ASP Outbound TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997849/classic-asp-outbound-tls-1-2)

I then recommend you continue use MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0, without the setoptions and getoption - they are not required