# Read Text File Content from HTTPS Web using VB6

Tags: https, get, vb6

I need source code for reading the .txt content from a HTTPS URL.
I have the one that successfully reads from a HTTP website, but i am having issues since my host forced HTTPS protocols on all URL.

The source code i use for HTTPS is :

```
Private Function GetHttpText(ByVal URL As String) As ADODB.Stream
    Dim Req As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim CharSet As String
    Dim CharsetPos As Long
    Dim LineSeparator As LineSeparatorEnum

    Set Req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Set GetHttpText = New ADODB.Stream
    With GetHttpText
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        With Req
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send
            CharSet = LCase$(.getResponseHeader("CONTENT-TYPE"))
        End With
        .Write Req.responseBody
        CharsetPos = InStr(CharSet, "charset")
        If CharsetPos Then
            CharSet = Split(Mid$(CharSet, CharsetPos), "=")(1)
        Else
            'UTF-8 is a reasonable "default" these days:
            CharSet = "utf-8"
        End If
        If CharSet = "utf-8" Then
            LineSeparator = adLF
        Else
            'Your milage may vary here, since there is no line-end
            'header defined for HTTP:
            LineSeparator = adCRLF
        End If
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeText
        .CharSet = CharSet
        .LineSeparator = LineSeparator
    End With
End Function

Private Sub DumpTextLineByLine()
    With GetHttpText("http://textfiles.com/art/simpsons.txt")
        'Read text line by line to populate a multiline TextBox
        'just as a demonstration:
        Do Until .EOS
            Text1.SelText = .ReadText(adReadLine)
            Text1.SelText = vbNewLine
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Above source code is courtesy **@Bob77**
But if i run the above for HTTPS website, i get the error of "Error Occurred in the Secure Channel Support"
Please help with a source code that can read successfully from HTTPS web.

Comment: MSXML handles HTTPS just fine. What OS are you using? Older versions of Windows (Win 7, Server <= 2008) miss TLS1.2 and it needs to be installed/enabled there in order for HTTPS to work. See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354992/an-error-occurred-in-the-secure-channel-support-classic-asp-http-request)

Comment: +Hel O'Ween and +StayOnTarget
Thank you SO SO SO MUCH. It solved my problem perfectly. I am grateful.